# iOS AdMob native ad crash when placed in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I'm trying to show native ad in **custom** UITableViewCell using **GADNativeExpressAdView**:

**AdCell.h:**

```
@interface AdCell : UITableViewCell

- (void)setAd:(WPRUIViewController*)parentController parentTable:(UITableView*)parentTable indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;

@end
```

**AdCell.m:**

```
#import "AdCell.h"

@interface AdCell()<GADNativeExpressAdViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak)     WPRUIViewController   *parentController;
@property (nonatomic, weak)     UITableView   *parentTableView;
@property (nonatomic, weak)     NSIndexPath   *indexPath;
@property (nonatomic, weak)      GADNativeExpressAdView *nativeExpressAdView;

@end

@implementation AdCell



+ (NSArray *)testDevices
{
    static NSArray *_testDevices;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _testDevices = @[kGADSimulatorID];
    });
    return _testDevices;
}


- (void)setAd:(WPRUIViewController*)parentController parentTable:(UITableView*)parentTable indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    self.parentController = parentController;
    self.parentTableView = parentTable;
    self.indexPath = indexPath;
    self.backgroundColor = ClearColor;
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = ClearColor;

    [self showExpressNativeAd];
}

- (void)showExpressNativeAd
{
    if (self.nativeExpressAdView == nil)
    {
        GADNativeExpressAdView *nativeExpressAdView = [[GADNativeExpressAdView alloc] initWithAdSize:GADAdSizeFromCGSize(self.contentView.size)];
        self.nativeExpressAdView = nativeExpressAdView;
        [self.contentView addSubview:nativeExpressAdView];

        self.nativeExpressAdView.adUnitID = AppModel.googleAdsKey;
        self.nativeExpressAdView.delegate = self;
        self.nativeExpressAdView.rootViewController = self.parentController;
        self.nativeExpressAdView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }




    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

    [self.nativeExpressAdView loadRequest:request];
}


- (void)nativeExpressAdViewDidReceiveAd:(GADNativeExpressAdView *)nativeExpressAdView
{

}

- (void)nativeExpressAdView:(GADNativeExpressAdView *)nativeExpressAdView didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
    [WPRLogger printError:error where:DEBUG_PLACE];
}
@end
```

- I'm calling `setAd:parentTable:indexPath` from within `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath` of ViewController.

My application constantly crashes with the following stack trace:

[image: Stack trace]

Comment: U know, how to integrate native express ads in tableview?